# Access a remote Ubuntu based system terminal in background?

Tags: command-line, networking, 18.04, server, remote-desktop

I need to access the terminal remotely of systems running Ubuntu 18.04 in my organisation for remote maintenance without hindering the working of the system hence it essentially needs to be in background. I am currently using Anydesk for the same but it has high consumption of internet bandwidth hence slowing down the process. **I need to remotely access the terminals of the systems which do not have a static ip**.  I can install the software / script required for remote access once.

Comment: If you only need to use the terminal remote, you should use `ssh`. I am not sure what you means by "in the background", you will always connect on an other session than other users (all users connect on separate sessions).

Comment: By "In background" I meant that the existing user operations should not be hindered while accessing the system on remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a job for ssh. Ssh will give you a shell in the target machine you can install it by

`sudo apt-get install ssh-server`

Unfortunately, if you want to access the device from outside the network you will need to configure port-forwarding or a VPN server for you to connect to the network, you can use the hostname of the device to connect to it.

Since it gives you a shell the user will not be interrupted

Comment: could you please share some reference around steps to set it up ?

Comment: Sure those tutorials can introduce you to the general concept https://www.howtogeek.com/221001/how-to-set-up-your-own-home-vpn-server/  https://hosting.review/tutorial/home-vpn-server/  The idea is to have an exit point within your network so you can connect to it from everywhere